# Как временно отключить редирект с http на https в nginx?

Tags: nginx

Конфигурационный файл настроен на редирект http --> https. Подскажите что надо изменить в файле, что бы сайт был доступен и по http и по https одновременно.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name first.com www.first.com;
    return 301 https://first.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name www.first.com;
        include snippets/ssl-first.com.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
        return 301 https://first.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        # SSL configuration

        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        include snippets/ssl-first.com.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

        ...
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
server_name first.com www.first.com;
```

Нужно заменить на:

```
server_name www.first.com;
```

Затем после `# SSL configuration` нужно добавить:

```
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
```

Перезапускаем nginx и пробуем:

```
curl -I http://first.com
```

Должно показать:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
... и так далее
```

Конечно, если у вас было включено HTST, то это поможет только для новых гостей сайта. Старые всё так же будут ходить по https.

Comment: Все равно редиректит

Comment: Перезапускали сервер? Может ещё браузерный кеш, попробуйте curl-ом напрямую.

Comment: Действительно кэш браузера, спасибо!